# Why MySQL nested Cursor fetch always return the first values?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

here is my stored procedure [gist address](https://gist.github.com/geosmart/c3d7f4eb0d9ad53751d7),
I have troubled for a lot hours with this sp!

Comment: I found the problem! i change the view to temporary table,and the right rows return! but I don't know why the view not work!

Comment: FETCH Into的结果总是父级Cursor(cursor_bizId)的第一个bizId的查询结果！why?

View的问题，换成temporary table，已解决，见gist